# ag-grid-angular - onKeyDown listener not being triggered with arrow keys

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

Scenario: I was using a custom cellEditor and when inside a cell (editing it), I could use the arrows key to move around the cells, but now that I removed the custom cellEditor, the arrow keys just moves *inside* cell's text.

I tried to search a way to change this behavior, but couldn't find it. So I was trying to "simulate" the behavior, listening to the keyDown ((keydown)="onKeyDown($event)") and if it's right arrow, move the position to right, up moves up, etc.
But for some reason, ALL keys triggers inside the cell, but it doesn't with the arrow keys.

ag-grid-angular: 18.0.1

angular: 10.2.5

Anyone ever had to do that, and could share some ideas?
Thanks! :D